# My JUnit tests don't fail when I execute them via maven

Tags: java, junit

I use `maven` on my test project and I wanted to test `test` option in maven's lifecycle, but I don't get my `JUnit` test failed.
I have `class` named Arithmetics in `src.main.java` package and `class` named ArithmeticsTest in `src.test.java` package.
When I run ArithmeticsTest on my own using IntelliJ Idea everuthing OK, and I have expected `java.lang.AssertionError`, so why I don't have such when I run test option in maven?

Console output:

> ---
>
> T E S T S
>
> ---
>
> Running ArithmeticsTest Configuring TestNG with:
> org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@44e81672
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.438
> sec Results : Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

src.main.java.Arithmetics.java

```
public class Arithmetics
{
    public static int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

src.test.java.ArithmeticsTest.java

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class ArithmeticsTest
{
    @Test
    public void testAdd()
    {
        assertEquals(4, Arithmetics.add(2, 3));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have configured maven to use TestNG but you are using JUnit annotations (`org.junit.Test`) and assertions (`org.junit.Assert.*`).

Remove TestNG from your dependencies and it should work.